# capture local network traffic

Tags: networking, capture, tcpdump

I have a PS3 and I am going to capture the PS3 traffic. However, how can I capture it with wireshark? Because when I capture it, it only shows the traffic to my computer only.

For example,

```
PC 192.168.1.101
PS3 192.168.1.102
```

How can I do to capture the traffic to PS3, by the way, I am using wireless router.

Can I use sth like tcpdump/ snoop on Mac too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do that on a device that the traffic actually goes through.  In other words, your router.  Chances are your wireless router doesn't have this capability, so you might need to set up a PC with two network cards that physically sits between your PS3 and your router.  Then you can run your packet-capture software on that PC and see everything that passes through to/from your PS3.

Comment: Or see http://www.miarec.com/knowledge/switches-port-mirroring there's a couple of inexpensive 5-port switches with port-mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac has both ethernet and wifi, set up "Internet Connection Sharing" on the wireless interface.

Connect the PS3 to that, and then connect the Mac to your router with its ethernet port.

All traffic from the PS3 to the net will then pass through the Mac, and you'll be able to use tcpdump or wireshark to see it in transit.

Answer (score 0):

If your wireless-router is separate from your DSL-modem, or if your PS3 can be connected using a wired network you can use a [passive networking tap](http://hackaday.com/2008/09/14/passive-networking-tap/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding tcpdump, yes, you absolutely can use it on a Mac. The easiest way to obtain it is using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), but if you have the experience (or fancy gaining the experience) you could also build it from source.